# How to switch between sessions in NetCat

Tags: netcat

I have a nc in listen mode

```
nc -klvmp 12345 --max-conns 3
```

I create 3 sessions. At the end I want to be able to switch on the server side between client's sessions. Or work in 1 and then close it and switch to second. How can I do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.